# Split String into Array Objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am getting response from web-service like this

```
Result =     (
            (
        "Test1",
        "Test2",
        "Test3",
        "Test4",
        Test5
    )
);
```

By, [dict objectForKey:@"Result"]; I am getting value

```
(
        "Test1",
        "Test2",
        "Test3",
        "Test4",
        Test5
    )
```

So, how can I get values in array format from NSSting format.

For eg. Array :- Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5

Can anyone reply please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give us more information on what you are receiving from the web-service. The Result you've shown is not ObjC at all so we have no clues to understand which datatype is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copied the printout exactly as formatted, it appears that the `@"Result"` key contains an array of arrays with a single element which is already the array that you wanr, so this should work for you:

```
NSArray *res = [[dict objectForKey:@"Result"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

The reason I think this is an array in an array is that it shows two levels of nested parentheses around the list.

Answer (score 3):

try This Code :

```
NSMutableArray* arrCountryName = (NSMutableArray *)[yourString componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
```

Comment: Why are you casting to `NSMutableArray`. Seems not a sensible things to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use your inputString and generate the Array output as follows:

```
NSString *inputString = @"Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4";
NSMutableArray* outputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
outputArray = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
```

If you need any more help them let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if([dict objectForKey:@"Result"] isKindofClass:[NSArray class]])
{

   NSArray *arrValues = [dict objectForKey:@"Result"];
  //u have your array 
  for(NSString *value in arrValues)
  {
    NSLog(@"%@",values);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *separatorString = @",";
NSScanner *aScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourString];
NSString *thingsScanned;
[aScanner scanUpToString:separatorString intoString:&thingsScanned];
NSLog(@"container: %@", thingsScanned);
```